# How to replace the certificate content in a file using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a CA CERT stored in a `Kubernetes_CA.crt`, now I need to place the content of the the file(Eg: the certificate) into a a 2nd file called `file-2`.
The `file-2` is currently in the following format.(including the `#`)

```
# some other important stuff here
abc: 123

# cert_manager_trusted_internal_ca: |
#   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#   [REPLACE with your CA certificate]
#   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have a CA CERT stored in a different file:

```
cat Kubernetes_CA.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFCzCCAvOgAwIBAgIUG4lkCNLVQ/tlDoJ+t5Tn8nRedS8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
FAKE-FAKEB0y+dqvqOsWPdH43+kO7tLw9k7WGw5G/TYSgjijoj7HjxHWEbkhzN99
yO7MKz0AK1VeicD2utw9m/AnpPmpDYnMxI62nvZZVdv1lXAJxU9q8x7hxKvpfvLl
mYz034eaoTfK6zNlo/ptAZeQwDcebMEeR//ld9Ko57jDIjydLb9cBhor0a+SQgJH
vBH+uiiKtrxris022nl61jYpHJ1tEcuoNT5EiCBtzOWMq85ICXH6Ay7FAKE-vqTW
OxFvsi0GSNmjYuM0ZGCP8C1Qgt7Xq9om1pQCAXcaJMSkc5IMD7NLYibRqNhUQFNA
IkeZN2dwDPbmgTftMWStaJO0QtOJwtYlX0681IRIHXxMJhLciOm8VpfFKBm575YY
PrsFAdEWvAL8h3HR2UfsRR52i2Yy1miXG54FKvDLON1JEwlcBKFVTJtIP0i5BtM=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

Now, I need to transform the input file into the following output:

```
# some other important stuff here
abc: 123

# cert_manager_trusted_internal_ca: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIFCzCCAvOgAwIBAgIUG4lkCNLVQ/tlDoJ+t5Tn8nRedS8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
    FAKE-FAKEB0y+dqvqOsWPdH43+kO7tLw9k7WGw5G/TYSgjijoj7HjxHWEbkhzN99
    yO7MKz0AK1VeicD2utw9m/AnpPmpDYnMxI62nvZZVdv1lXAJxU9q8x7hxKvpfvLl
    mYz034eaoTfK6zNlo/ptAZeQwDcebMEeR//ld9Ko57jDIjydLb9cBhor0a+SQgJH
    vBH+uiiKtrxris022nl61jYpHJ1tEcuoNT5EiCBtzOWMq85ICXH6Ay7FAKE-vqTW
    OxFvsi0GSNmjYuM0ZGCP8C1Qgt7Xq9om1pQCAXcaJMSkc5IMD7NLYibRqNhUQFNA
    IkeZN2dwDPbmgTftMWStaJO0QtOJwtYlX0681IRIHXxMJhLciOm8VpfFKBm575YY
    PrsFAdEWvAL8h3HR2UfsRR52i2Yy1miXG54FKvDLON1JEwlcBKFVTJtIP0i5BtM=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I do not have `yq` installed, hoping to do this in with `sed` or `awk`.

I have already tried the following:

Extracted the certificate between `---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---` and `--END CERTIFICATE--` tags from the `Kubernetes_CA.crt` file:

```
awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/{flag=1; next} /END CERTIFICATE/{flag=0} flag'  Kubernetes_CA.crt 
MIIFCzCCAvOgAwIBAgIUG4lkCNLVQ/tlDoJ+t5Tn8nRedS8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
FAKE-FAKEB0y+dqvqOsWPdH43+kO7tLw9k7WGw5G/TYSgjijoj7HjxHWEbkhzN99
yO7MKz0AK1VeicD2utw9m/AnpPmpDYnMxI62nvZZVdv1lXAJxU9q8x7hxKvpfvLl
mYz034eaoTfK6zNlo/ptAZeQwDcebMEeR//ld9Ko57jDIjydLb9cBhor0a+SQgJH
vBH+uiiKtrxris022nl61jYpHJ1tEcuoNT5EiCBtzOWMq85ICXH6Ay7FAKE-vqTW
OxFvsi0GSNmjYuM0ZGCP8C1Qgt7Xq9om1pQCAXcaJMSkc5IMD7NLYibRqNhUQFNA
IkeZN2dwDPbmgTftMWStaJO0QtOJwtYlX0681IRIHXxMJhLciOm8VpfFKBm575YY
PrsFAdEWvAL8h3HR2UfsRR52i2Yy1miXG54FKvDLON1JEwlcBKFVTJtIP0i5BtM=
```

Tried to do replacement with command substitution but it is failing:

```
sed -r "s/^#//g;s/.*REPLACE.*/$(awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/{flag=1; next} /END CERTIFICATE/{flag=0} flag'  Kubernetes_CA.crt)" file-2  
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Simplest is `cp Kubernetes_CA.crt file-2` since the `#` lines are ignored comments.

Comment: @stark see the desired result in the question. the file-2 is having other attributes also, so cannot do plain copy.

Comment: In that case use `cat`

Comment: Is `#   -----END CERTIFICATE-----` always last line of 1st file or there might be text to keep after it?

Comment: @Daweo there could be more stuff after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this single `sed` command for this:

```bash
# create indentation
sed 's/^/    /' Kubernetes_CA.crt > temp.crt

# use indented cert in sed
sed -i.bak -E -e '/^# *-+BEGIN /,/^# *-+END / {/-END /r temp.crt' -e ';d;}' file-2

cat file-2

# some other important stuff here
abc: 123

# cert_manager_trusted_internal_ca: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIFCzCCAvOgAwIBAgIUG4lkCNLVQ/tlDoJ+t5Tn8nRedS8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
    FAKE-FAKEB0y+dqvqOsWPdH43+kO7tLw9k7WGw5G/TYSgjijoj7HjxHWEbkhzN99
    yO7MKz0AK1VeicD2utw9m/AnpPmpDYnMxI62nvZZVdv1lXAJxU9q8x7hxKvpfvLl
    mYz034eaoTfK6zNlo/ptAZeQwDcebMEeR//ld9Ko57jDIjydLb9cBhor0a+SQgJH
    vBH+uiiKtrxris022nl61jYpHJ1tEcuoNT5EiCBtzOWMq85ICXH6Ay7FAKE-vqTW
    OxFvsi0GSNmjYuM0ZGCP8C1Qgt7Xq9om1pQCAXcaJMSkc5IMD7NLYibRqNhUQFNA
    IkeZN2dwDPbmgTftMWStaJO0QtOJwtYlX0681IRIHXxMJhLciOm8VpfFKBm575YY
    PrsFAdEWvAL8h3HR2UfsRR52i2Yy1miXG54FKvDLON1JEwlcBKFVTJtIP0i5BtM=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**`sed` explanation:**

- `/^# *-+BEGIN /,/^# *-+END /`: Match file block from commented `BEGIN` line to `END` line
- `{`: Start command block
- `/-END /r temp.crt`: For line matching `-END`  paste content from file `temp.crt`
- `d`: Delete range of lines
- `}`: command block

Comment: Hey Anubhav,  Can you please let me know if its possible to right-indent the certificate content by 4 places ? . Also, needless to say...whole command is going above my head :)

Comment: Other that indentation is everything else working for you? We can pre-indent cert data before running this sed. Will add some explanation in answer.

Comment: yes, its working except indentation. appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirt `awk`:

```
$ awk '
/^# cert_manager_trusted_internal_ca: \|/ {
        print;
        while (getline < "Kubernetes_CA.crt")
                print "    ", $0;
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
                getline;
        next;
} 1' file-2
# some other important stuff here
abc: 123

# cert_manager_trusted_internal_ca: |
     -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     MIIFCzCCAvOgAwIBAgIUG4lkCNLVQ/tlDoJ+t5Tn8nRedS8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
     FAKE-FAKEB0y+dqvqOsWPdH43+kO7tLw9k7WGw5G/TYSgjijoj7HjxHWEbkhzN99
     yO7MKz0AK1VeicD2utw9m/AnpPmpDYnMxI62nvZZVdv1lXAJxU9q8x7hxKvpfvLl
     mYz034eaoTfK6zNlo/ptAZeQwDcebMEeR//ld9Ko57jDIjydLb9cBhor0a+SQgJH
     vBH+uiiKtrxris022nl61jYpHJ1tEcuoNT5EiCBtzOWMq85ICXH6Ay7FAKE-vqTW
     OxFvsi0GSNmjYuM0ZGCP8C1Qgt7Xq9om1pQCAXcaJMSkc5IMD7NLYibRqNhUQFNA
     IkeZN2dwDPbmgTftMWStaJO0QtOJwtYlX0681IRIHXxMJhLciOm8VpfFKBm575YY
     PrsFAdEWvAL8h3HR2UfsRR52i2Yy1miXG54FKvDLON1JEwlcBKFVTJtIP0i5BtM=
     -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```